# How to create ORC (or parquet) files in javascript?

Tags: javascript, pyarrow, apache-arrow

In a server-side javascript module I need to write data to an ORC file but couldn't find any clue on how to do that. Ideally, my module should also be able to alternatively write to a parquet file. For the ORC case, I would also be interested in how to do that in python.

For the parquet case, I have seen this being done in python by using the [pyarrow library for Apache-Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/formats.html?highlight=parquet). The [Apache Arrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/index.html) claims that both ORC and parquet file formats are supported. There is also an [Apache Arrow node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apache-arrow) but in their [API reference](http://arrow.apache.org/docs/js/) I can't find anything on ORC or parquet.

Here on SO I found references to the [parquetjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parquetjs) and [node-parquet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-parquet) node modules, but nothing for ORC. Also, if possible I would prefer to use Apache Arrow.

Anyone have any pointers for me?

UPDATE: Apache-Arrow now supports [reading and writing ORC files](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/orc.html) in the Python implementation. No news on Javascript, though...

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Your question prompted me to throw together a [little proof-of-concept](https://github.com/trxcllnt/arrow-to-parquet-js/blob/b21682bd96915843fc218f20b0ee9bc0b355f9bc/index.js) to do arrow -> parquetjs. It's unfortunate that parquetjs has a row-oriented writer, but piping the table rows iterator through the writer seems to work fine:

```
$ node index.js 
{ int: 0, str: 'foo' }
{ int: 1, str: 'bar' }
{ int: 2, str: 'baz' }
```

**Original answer:**

We don't have support for reading or writing parquet in ArrowJS. I don't know the maturity of the node parquet implementations, so I haven't explored what sort of interop is possible between ArrowJS and ParquetJS yet.

So far the way I've solved this is to use pyarrow to write parquet files when necessary, usually at the boundaries when we want to read or write to long-term storage. I realize this is only a solution if you can afford to also stand up some python services.

If not (and it's a relatively infrequent operation, or you can afford to wait while the python interpreter starts up), you can have some quick'n dirty fun with dynamic languages by spawning a python child process from node and piping the tables through pyarrow:

```js
const duplexer = require('duplexer')
const { finished: eos } = require('stream')
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const { RecordBatchWriter } = require('apache-arrow')

const writer = new RecordBatchWriter()
writer.writeAll(your_arrow_table()).close()
await eos(writer.pipe(to_parquet_file('out/file.parquet')))

function spawn_python_script(code) {
    const child = spawn('python', ['-c', code]);
    return duplexer(child.stdin, child.stdout);
}

function to_parquet_file(out_path) {
    return spawn_python_script(`
import sys
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# read all the batches in from stdin
table = pa.RecordBatchStreamReader(sys.stdin.buffer).read_all()

# write table to the out_path
pq.write_table(table, '${out_path}')

sys.stdout.write('wrote table to \'${out_path}\')
sys.stdout.flush()
`)
}
```

If you save the python script to a file and read the path from `sys.argv[1]`, python will be a bit quicker to start up (but still a second or two).

I'm not familiar with the ORC libs, but I'd imagine there's some sort of parquet <-> ORC conversion in one of their Python APIs. I've found that unfortunately most of these tools don't exist in JS, or if they do, are nascent/abandoned (which is why we had to write the ArrowJS implementation).

It's a shame, because node is quite decent at i/o these days, and achieving the same throughput via python involves a fair amount of digging into the newest [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)/ASGI libs. Frameworks like [Quart](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/) and [Hypercorn](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/) are awesome, but being so bleeding-edge it can be difficult to find answers online when you do run into trouble [/rant].

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I gahter ORC or parquet integration is not really in the works for Apache ArrowJS, at this point? Since the main focus of my question is ORC I'm not yet setting this as the most helpful answer although it might well end up being that in the end... :-)